Ошибка 404 при доступе к сервлету в Tomcat 9.0.91
Я развернул приложение LearnServlet на сервере Tomcat 9.0.91. Основная страница (index.jsp) открывается корректно по адресу http://localhost:8080/LearnServlet/.
Однако при попытке открыть сервлет по адресу http://localhost:8080/LearnServlet/hello получаю ошибку 404. В логах catalina.out и localhost отсутствуют ошибки.
Детали окружения:
ОС: Windows 11 (64-bit)
Java: JDK 22.0.1 (Oracle)
Tomcat: 9.0.91
Структура проекта*
LearnServlet.war/
index.jsp
WEB-INF/
classes/
com/example/HelloServlet.class
Код сервлета:
java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = resp.getWriter();
        printWriter.write("<html>\n" +
                "    <body>\n" +
                "        <h1>Hello User!</h1>\n" +
                "    </body>\n" +
                "</html>");
        printWriter.close();
    }
}

Что пробовал:
Убедился, что Tomcat запускается без ошибок (логи catalina.out и localhost).
Проверил, что основная страница index.jsp открывается.
Структура WAR-файла соответствует требованиям (WEB-INF и .class-файлы на месте).
Пробовал аннотации результат одинаковый.
Очистил кэш браузера и проверил с разными браузерами.
zВопрос:
Что может быть причиной ошибки 404 при доступе к сервлету? Какие дополнительные проверки стоит выполнить?

Что происходит при попытке доступа к ресурсу http://localhost:8080/hello ?

Тоже ошибку 404. Но доступ же должен происходить по адресу http://localhost:8080/LearnServlet/hello ведь LearnServlet это имя приложения

Я не специалист в данной области, но может быть стоит посмотреть/попробовать использовать web.xml для указания параметров сервлетов?
